# How can I remove the kivy.require statement within KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

Last 2 months ago, I was able to make my app work by building it in Google Collab and with the necessary buildozer file.

I am planning to build the app again because of minor changes, however upon launching the app, the app crashes. I used adb logcat to check the error and upon checking it, it generates this error:

```
02-15 22:46:41.308  9769 14717 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
02-15 22:46:41.308  9769 14717 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
02-15 22:46:41.308  9769 14717 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/ltlann/arm64-v8a/kivymd/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
02-15 22:46:41.309  9769 14717 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/ltlann/arm64-v8a/kivy/__init__.py", line 130, in require
02-15 22:46:41.309  9769 14717 I python  :  Exception: The version of Kivy installed on this system is too old. (You have 2.1.0, but the application requires 2.2.0)
02-15 22:46:41.309  9769 14717 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Upon checking, it states that the first statement causes the error. However, the first statement is:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
```

For my app to work, I can only stick with Kivy 2.1.0, because whenever I use other versions of kivy, the camera feature of the application doesn't work. Moreover, I usually include this link: https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip within the buildozer file, specifically for the app requirement.

Is there a way I can bypass this by changing the requirement or removing it if necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line kivy.require("2.2.0") to kivy.require("2.1.0"), or another kivy version, in **init**.py in the kivymd folder (/KIVYMD-MASTER/kivymd/__init__.py)

The kivy.require checks the minimun version required to run the application and generates an exception when that is not satisfied. This is the issue you experiencing.

You can check the kivy website documentation to understant better. follows the link [https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.html](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.html.)